# Is there a way to know how many session that open a particular table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate unique id using php for a table 
ex: 2013-10-24-01 (yyyy-mm-dd-last_index_plus_1).
The problem is, if there are two session simultaneous open the php 
which is access a same table, the generate unique id will be same on them. 
I come up with idea that determined the number of session accessing that table 
and then plus the last_index by that number, 
but i don't know how to accomplished it with mysql. 
Is it possible or not?

Thanks

Comment: there some reason you are not using auto inc and say date inserted.

Comment: Try inserting the unique ID into the table. If it fails because of a duplicate key, increment the index and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment I am not sure why you want PHP to actually do this, and why the auto_increment is not good enough, but if you need a unique ID you can do the following:

1. Make sure to add a unique key on the column you are inserting into - if something goes wrong your database will make sure you won't get the two identical keys. In theory you could try until the query succeeds from PHP
2. You can use the "select for update" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) when selecting the last known sequence to make sure that another process will not try to read before you have inserted it.

The above is possible to do in mysql using a trigger, as you did not provide any structure, the below is just an example of how it could look. It uses a sequence-table for selecting the last id, and the mysql date_format function to format the inserted date.

```
delimiter |
create trigger `trigger_name` 
  before insert on `table_name`
    for each row begin
      set new.last_id = concat(date_format(now(), '%y-%m-%d'), '-', (select max(id) from `sequence_table` for update));
end|

delimiter ;
```